# Tungsten replicator for two master Oracle databases

Tags: oracle11g, replication, tungsten-replicator

Would I be able to set up bi-directional replication between two Oracle databases using Tungsten replicator? That is, both are masters.

Both Oracle databases are in the same network. Both are 11g databases. One serves a web site (standard edition with CPU based license) and the other serves an internal application (enterprise edition with user based license).

If this is possible, could it be synchronous?

I'm reading the documentation. But I don't have my specific questions answered yet. If you are pointing me to the documentation, I appreciate it if you are specific about the part you want me to look at.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone searching:

The online documentation only talks about Oracle to MySql replication. I contacted the vendor and discussed the requirement. According to them it's feasible. However, if you have a lot of triggers (bad practice) then you're dealing with a very complex configuration.